# Genericizing PropertyValues

Tags: c#, generics, hash-map, enum

This should be the last iteration for this code.

1. Does this approach make sense or am I heading down the wrong path?
2. The only thing I can see to make this better is to genericize the `GetType` methods at the end so that I could eliminate the goofy `if` statement in the `GetProperties` method.  Any suggestions?

What I've done between the last question and now:

I've used a private method `GetProperty` as suggested in the last question in order to minimize the repeated code.

```
private object GetProperty(string propertyName)
{
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
        ("SELECT " + propertyName + " FROM " + WmiClassName))
    using (var collection = moSearcher.Get())
    using (var enu = collection.GetEnumerator())
        return (!enu.MoveNext() || enu.Current[propertyName] == null) ? null : enu.Current[propertyName];
}
```

#### Step 1

I decided to edit the `PropertyValue` class along these lines to handle the dictionary

```
public PropertyValue(Dictionary<string, string> propertyList, string wmiClassName).
```

Where the first string in the dictionary is the type the property will return and second in the dictionary is the `propertyName` as a string so that it is easy to work with.  I'd like to genericize the type part so I could use a list or array instead of a dictionary.  Really just to eliminate one of the string variables.

#### Step 2

I updated the calls to the `WMIClasses`:

```
public class Win32Processor
{

    public Win32Processor() { }

    readonly PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue("Win32_Processor");

    /// <summary>
    /// Processor architecture used by the platform.
    /// </summary>
    public ushort Architecture()
    { return propertyValue.GetUnignedInt16("Architecture"); }

    /// <summary>
    /// Description of the object. This property is inherited from CIM_ManagedSystemElement.
    /// </summary>
    public string Description()
    { return propertyValue.GetString("Description"); }
}
```

To...

```
public class Win32BaseBoard
{

public object GetValues()
    {
    Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        {"ushort", "AddressWidth"},

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        {"ushort", "Architecture"},};

        // ...

        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_BaseBoard");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}
```

Then I went about refactoring my `PropertyValue` class.

After implementing all of the above here's the full code as it stands:

```
#region WMI Classes

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_BaseBoard WMI class represents a baseboard, which is also known as a motherboard or system board.
/// </summary>
public class Win32BaseBoard
{
    public Win32BaseBoard() { }

    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){

            {"ushort", "AddressWidth"},

            {"ushort", "Architecture"},

            {"ushort", "Availability"},

            {"ushort", "CpuStatus"},

            {"uint", "CurrentClockSpeed"},

            {"ushort", "DataWidth"},

            {"string", "Description"},


            {"string", "DeviceID"},

            {"uint", "ExtClock"},


            {"ushort", "Family"},


            {"uint", "L2CacheSize"},


            {"uint", "L2CacheSpeed"},


            {"ushort", "Level"},

            {"ushort", "LoadPercentage"},


            {"string", "Manufacturer"},


            {"uint", "MaxClockSpeed"},


            {"string", "Name"},


            {"uint", "NumberOfCores"},

            {"string", "PNPDeviceID"},

            {"string", "ProcessorId"},

            {"ushort", "ProcessorType"},

            {"ushort", "Revision"},

            {"string", "Role"},

            {"string", "SocketDesignation"},

            {"ushort", "StatusInfo"},

            {"string", "Stepping"},

            {"string", "UniqueId"},

            {"ushort", "UpgradeMethod"},

            {"string", "Version"},

            {"uint", "VoltageCaps"},
        };
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_BaseBoard");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_BIOS WMI class represents the attributes of the computer system's basic input/output services (BIOS) 
/// that are installed on a computer.
/// </summary>
public class Win32BIOS
{

    public Win32BIOS() { }

    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){

            {"string", "BankLabel"},

            {"string", "BuildNumber"},

            {"ulong", "Capacity"},

            {"string", "CurrentLanguage"},

            {"ushort", "DataWidth"},

            {"string", "Description"},

            {"ushort", "FormFactor"},

            {"bool", "HotSwappable"},

            {"string", "InstallableLanguages"},

            {"string", "Manufacturer"},

            {"ushort", "MemoryType"},

            {"string", "Name"},

            {"string", "PartNumber"},

            {"uint", "PositionInRow"},

            {"datetime", "ReleaseDate"},

            {"string", "SerialNumber"},

            {"string", "SMBIOSMajorVersion"},

            {"string", "SMBIOSMinorVersion"},

            {"bool", "SMBIOSPresent"},

            {"string", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion"},

            {"uint", "Speed"},

            {"string", "Status"},

            {"string", "Tag"},

            {"ushort", "TypeDetail"},

            {"string", "Version"}
        };
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_BIOS");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }


}

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_DiskDrive WMI class represents a physical disk drive as seen by a computer running the Windows 
/// operating system. Any interface to a Windows physical disk drive is a descendent (or member) of this class. 
/// The features of the disk drive seen through this object correspond to the logical and management 
/// characteristics of the drive. In some cases, this may not reflect the actual physical characteristics 
/// of the device. Any object based on another logical device would not be a member of this class.
/// For security reasons, a user connecting from a remote computer must have the SC_MANAGER_CONNECT privilege 
/// enabled to be able to enumerate this class.
/// </summary>
public class Win32DiskDrive
{
    public Win32DiskDrive() { }

    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Description"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Manufacturer"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Model"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Name"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "OtherIdentifyingInfo"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "PartNumber"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Product"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "RequirementsDescription"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "SerialNumber"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "SKU"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "SlotLayout"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"bool", "SpecialRequirements"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Tag"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Version"}
        };
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_DiskDrive");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_DiskPartition WMI class represents the capabilities and management capacity of a partitioned area 
/// of a physical disk on a computer system running Windows. Example: Disk #0, Partition #1.
/// </summary>
public class Win32DiskPartion
{
    public Win32DiskPartion() { }

    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Name"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"bool", "PrimaryBIOS"}
        };
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_DiskPartion");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_ComputerSystem WMI class represents a computer system running Windows.
/// </summary>
public class Win32ComputerSystem
{

    public Win32ComputerSystem() { }

    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            /// <summary>
            /// Key of a CIM_System instance in an enterprise environment.
            /// This property is inherited from CIM_ManagedSystemElement.
            /// </summary>   
            {"string", "Name"},

            /// <summary>
            /// Name of a computer manufacturer.
            /// </summary>  
            {"string", "Manufacturer"},

            /// <summary>
            /// Product name that a manufacturer gives to a computer. This property must have a value.
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Model"}
    };
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_ComputerSystem");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_LogicalDisk WMI class represents a data source that resolves to an actual local storage device 
/// on a computer system running Windows.
/// </summary>
public class Win32LogicalDisk
{
    public Win32LogicalDisk() { }

    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "BytesPerSector"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ushort", "Capabilities"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Caption"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "DeviceID"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"suint", "Index"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "InterfaceType"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Manufacturer"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"bool", "MediaLoaded"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "MediaType"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Model"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Name"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "Partitions"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "PNPDeviceID"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "SCSIBus"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ushort", "SCSILogicalUnit"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ushort", "SCSIPort"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ushort", "SCSITargetId"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "SectorsPerTrack"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "Signature"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ulong", "Size"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Status"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ulong", "TotalCylinders"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "TotalHeads"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ulong", "TotalSectors"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ulong", "TotalTracks"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "TracksPerCylinder"}
        };
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_LogicalDisk");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_OperatingSystem WMI class represents a Windows-based OS installed on a computer. Any OS that can be 
/// installed on a computer that can run a Windows-based OS is a descendent or member of this class. 
/// Win32_OperatingSystem is a singleton class. To get the single instance, use "@" for the key.
/// </summary>
public class Win32OperatingSystem
{
    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            /// <summary>
            /// Number, in megabytes, of physical memory currently unused and available.
            /// </summary>    
            {"ulong", "FreePhysicalMemory"},
            /// <summary>
            /// Number, in megabytes, of virtual memory currently unused and available.
            /// </summary>    
            {"ulong", "FreeVirtualMemory"},
            /// <summary>
            /// Number, in megabytes, of virtual memory.
            /// </summary>
            {"ulong", "TotalVirtualMemory"}
        };
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_OperatingSystem");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_PhysicalMemory WMI class represents a physical memory device located on a computer system and 
/// available to the operating system.
/// </summary>
public class Win32PhysicalMemory
{
    public Win32PhysicalMemory() { }

    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary> 
            {"ulong", "BlockSize"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"bool", "Bootable"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"bool", "BootPartition"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Description"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "DeviceID"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ushort", "DiskIndex"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ushort", "Index"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Name"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ulong", "NumberOfBlocks"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"bool", "PrimaryPartition"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ulong", "Size"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"ulong", "StartingOffset"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Type"}
        };

        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_PhysicalMemory");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The Win32_Processor WMI class represents a device that can interpret a sequence of instructions on a computer 
/// running on a Windows operating system. On a multiprocessor computer, one instance of the Win32_Processor class 
/// exists for each processor.
/// </summary>
public class Win32Processor
{

    public Win32Processor() { }

    public object GetValues()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
            /// <summary>
            /// Key of a CIM_System instance in an enterprise environment.
            /// This property is inherited from CIM_ManagedSystemElement.
            /// </summary>   
            {"ushort", "Architecture"},

            /// <summary>
            /// Name of a computer manufacturer.
            /// </summary>  
            {"string", "Description"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "DeviceID"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "DriveType"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "FileSystem"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"uint", "MediaType"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"string", "Name"},

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            {"bool", "VolumeDirty"}
        };
        PropertyValue propertyValue = new PropertyValue(propertyList, "Win32_Processor");
        return propertyValue.GetProperties();
    }
}

#endregion

#region PropertyValue
/// <summary>
/// Handles the actual WMI queries for the other classes in this file
/// </summary>
public class PropertyValue
{

    public PropertyValue() { }

    public PropertyValue(Dictionary<string, string> propertyList, string wmiClassName)
    {
        this.PropertyList = propertyList;
        this.WmiClassName = wmiClassName;
    }

    public string WmiClassName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> PropertyList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts kilobyte values to megabytes for readability.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kiloBytes">Value to be converted</param>
    /// <returns>Kilobytes converted to megabytes as ulong</returns>
    private static ulong KiloBytesToMegaBytes(ulong kiloBytes)
    { return kiloBytes / (ulong)1024; }

    public object GetProperties()
    {
        foreach (var pair in PropertyList)
        {
            if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "datetime")
            { return GetDateTimeFromDmtf(pair.Value); }
            if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "string")
            { return GetString(pair.Value); }
            if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "ulong")
            { return GetUnsignedInt64(pair.Value); }
            if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "bool")
            { return GetBool(pair.Value); }
            if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "ushort")
            { return GetUnignedInt16(pair.Value); }
            if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "uint")
            { return GetUnsignedInt32(pair.Value); }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private uint GetUnsignedInt32(string propertyName)
    {
        var property = FindProperty(propertyName);
        return property == null ? (uint)(0) : (uint)(property);
    }

    private object FindProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher
            ("SELECT " + propertyName + " FROM " + WmiClassName))
        using (var collection = moSearcher.Get())
        using (var enu = collection.GetEnumerator())
            return (!enu.MoveNext() || enu.Current[propertyName] == null) ? null : enu.Current[propertyName];

    }

    private DateTime GetDateTimeFromDmtf(string propertyName)
    {
        var property = FindProperty(propertyName);
        return property == null ? DateTime.Today : ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(property.ToString());
    }

    private string GetString(string propertyName)
    {
        var property = FindProperty(propertyName);
        return property == null ? String.Empty : property.ToString();
    }

    private ulong GetUnsignedInt64(string propertyName)
    {
        var property = FindProperty(propertyName);
        return property == null ? (ulong)(0) : KiloBytesToMegaBytes((ulong)(property));
    }

    private bool GetBool(string propertyName)
    {
        var property = FindProperty(propertyName);
        return property == null ? false : true;
    }

    private ushort GetUnignedInt16(string propertyName)
    {
        var property = FindProperty(propertyName);
        return property == null ? (ushort)(0) : (ushort)(property);
    }
}
#endregion
```

**Questions in this series**

[Class Seperation vs Polymorphism.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43432/class-seperation-vs-polymorphism)

[First iteration of DRY refactoring.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43598/should-i-refactor-for-dry)

[Second iteration of DRY refactoring.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43719/next-instance-of-dry-refactoring)

You are currently viewing the fourth question in the series.

Answer (score 6):

First:

```
        if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "datetime")
        { return GetDateTimeFromDmtf(pair.Value); }
        if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "string")
        { return GetString(pair.Value); }
        if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "ulong")
        { return GetUnsignedInt64(pair.Value); }
        if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "bool")
        { return GetBool(pair.Value); }
        if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "ushort")
        { return GetUnignedInt16(pair.Value); }
        if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "uint")
        { return GetUnsignedInt32(pair.Value); }
```

Screaming to be a `switch` statement.

Second, these guys in every `GetValues` method:

```
Dictionary<string, string> propertyList = new Dictionary<string, string>(){

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    {"ushort", "AddressWidth"},

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    {"ushort", "Architecture"},};
```

a) are immutable once created, so it makes better sense to make them class-level variables. So they're initialized only once.
b) should then be `readonly`.
c) should be declared as `IDictionary<string, string>` so that you're developing against an interface rather than an implementation. This will need to be changed throughout method signatures, etc.

Third: `GetUnignedInt16` really should be spelled correctly. `GetUnsignedInt16`.

Fourth: `GetProperties()` in the `PropertyValue` class does not "get properties". It gets a single property. It takes the `Dictionary`, but only returns the first property value (this is due to `return` being in the `foreach` loop. My guess is maybe you mean to add to a list or array?). Seems like a misnaming and a bug at the same time. Fix the code before the review.

Those are initial thoughts.

Comment: If `GetProperties()` is actually supposed to return all properties, simply writing it with `yield return` will do the trick.

Comment: And with the required `IEnumerable<object>` return type. `yield return` methods must have a collection return type.

Comment: A minor issue: You should use `.ToUpperInvariant`. It will probably never matter, but `ToUpper` is "better" than `ToLower` -- I don't have a link to the actual reason, but I believe it is really only an issue for some Unicode characters. And similarly using the `Invariant` culture mostly just avoids Code Analysis warnings, but they are there for a (most unlikely) reason.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't been online in quite some time, but anyway ..

#### Review

- You are not using the `defaultValueIfEmpty` from previous post. This means `return (!enu.MoveNext() || enu.Current[propertyName] == null) ? null : enu.Current[propertyName];` can be shortened to `return !enu.MoveNext() ? null : enu.Current[propertyName];`.
- Use a better key as `String`, prefer `Type`. You don't need any shenanigans with casing keys. Refactor `Dictionary<string, string> propertyList` to `Dictionary<Type, string> propertyList`.
- `public object GetValues()` returns a single value. This seems more a bug than as designed.
- `ulong KiloBytesToMegaBytes` there is a lot of misconception about these units. Check out [Megabyte vs Mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

Comment: This mebibyte is a funny unit; and apparently nobody likes it :P

Comment: It was an attempt at generalising units. But even my teacher in uni, who worked at IBM haven't heard about it :-p It is interesting though, that many different variations of formulas are used.